# Web Api C# Endpoint don't work as POST

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

I'm having a problem with a end point that I created

```
    [Route("api/pag_seguro/transactions/credit_card")]
    public string DoTransactionWithCreditCard(string senderHash, string cardHash, ProductModels[] products)
    {
        bool isSandbox = true;
        EnvironmentConfiguration.ChangeEnvironment(isSandbox);

        // Instantiate a new checkout
        CreditCardCheckout checkout = new CreditCardCheckout();

        // Sets the payment mode
        checkout.PaymentMode = PaymentMode.DEFAULT;

        // Sets the receiver e-mail should will get paid
        checkout.ReceiverEmail = "financeiro@proteste.org.br";

        // Sets the currency
        checkout.Currency = Currency.Brl;

        // Add items
        checkout.Items.Add(new Item("0001", "Garrafa Laranja Tupperware", 1, 130.98m));

        // Sets a reference code for this checkout, it is useful to identify this payment in future notifications.
        checkout.Reference = "REFPT0002";

        // Sets shipping information.
        checkout.Shipping = new Shipping();
        checkout.Shipping.ShippingType = ShippingType.Sedex;
        checkout.Shipping.Cost = 0.00m;
        checkout.Shipping.Address = new Address(
            "BRA",
            "SP",
            "Sao Paulo",
            "Jardim Paulistano",
            "01452002",
            "Av. Brig. Faria Lima",
            "1384",
            "5o andar"
        );

        // Sets a credit card token. -- gerado em 06/03/2017
        checkout.Token = cardHash;

        //Sets the installments information
        checkout.Installment = new Installment(1, 130.98m, 2);

        // Sets credit card holder information.
        checkout.Holder = new Holder(
            "Holder Name",
            new Phone("11", "56273440"),
            new HolderDocument(Documents.GetDocumentByType("CPF"), "12345678909"),
            "01/10/1980"
        );

        // Sets shipping information.
        checkout.Billing = new Billing();
        checkout.Billing.Address = new Address(
            "BRA",
            "SP",
            "Sao Paulo",
            "Jardim Paulistano",
            "01452002",
            "Av. Brig. Faria Lima",
            "1384",
            "5o andar"
        );

        // Sets your customer information.
        // If you using SANDBOX you must use an email @sandbox.pagseguro.com.br
        checkout.Sender = new Sender(
            "Diogo Amaral",
            "comprador@sandbox.pagseguro.com.br",
            new Phone("21", "992947883")
        );
        checkout.Sender.Hash = senderHash;

        SenderDocument senderCPF = new SenderDocument(Documents.GetDocumentByType("CPF"), "12345678909");
        checkout.Sender.Documents.Add(senderCPF);

        try
        {
            AccountCredentials credentials = PagSeguroConfiguration.Credentials(isSandbox);
            Transaction result = TransactionService.CreateCheckout(credentials, checkout);
            //return result.TransactionStatus.ToString();
            return result.Code.ToString();
        }
        catch (PagSeguroServiceException exception)
        {
            string errorstr = "";

            foreach (Uol.PagSeguro.Domain.ServiceError erro in exception.Errors)
            {
                errorstr += erro.ToString();
            }

            return exception.Message + " - code: " + exception.StatusCode.ToString() + " - errors: " + exception.Errors.ToString() + " - errorstr: " + errorstr;
        }
    }
```

What is happening is that when I try to send a POST to this endpoint it doesn't work, it only accepts GET. What should I have to do to this become a POST endpoint?

I'm new on it, please help me guys. Thank you!

Now my code looks like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/pag_seguro/transactions/credit_card")]
    public string DoTransactionWithCreditCard(string senderHash, string cardHash, ProductModels[] products)
    {
        bool isSandbox = true;
        EnvironmentConfiguration.ChangeEnvironment(isSandbox);

        // Instantiate a new checkout
        CreditCardCheckout checkout = new CreditCardCheckout();
        ...
    }
```

But in console I still receiving 404 Not found error in Chrome console:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:40379/api/pag_seguro/transactions/credit_card
Request Method:POST
Status Code:404 Not Found
```

Comment: Did you mark it to post? [HttpPost] attribute tag?

Comment: yes, yes... I edited my first question with the attempts after you ask me to do that

Comment: By convention, if your action method has a single parameter which is a complex type(class), it will default to `post`, else it will default to `get`. And as far as I know, you cannot have multiple arguments in a post action, you need to make a class for that. Try extracting those three parameters into a class as properties and accept that class instance in the action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `[HttpPost]` attribute to tell Web API it should accept the POST verb.

Comment: I do that, but still not working. Look the response in console Request URL:localhost:40379/api/pag_seguro/transactions/credit_card Request Method:POST Status Code:404 Not Found

Comment: Are you calling `MapHttpAttributeRoutes()` in your web api configuration?

Answer (score 2):

Add `[HttpPost]`:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/pag_seguro/transactions/credit_card")]
public string DoTransactionWithCreditCard(string senderHash, string cardHash, ProductModels[] products)
```

Also make sure your `RouteConfig` contains `routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes()`:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        //Other stuff

        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes(); //make sure this is there
    }
}
```

Comment: I do that, but still not working. Look the response in console 
Request URL:http://localhost:40379/api/pag_seguro/transactions/credit_card
Request Method:POST
Status Code:404 Not Found

Answer (score 0):

1) Go to App_Start directory in your project and modify file for Web Api configuration called WebApiConfig.css (add  line `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();` in order to turn on Route attribute)

```
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

2) add attribute `[Post]` before your WebAPI method.

Answer (score 0):

You should define Request entity something like:

```
  public class PayRequest {
        public string senderHash;
        public string cardHash;
        public ProductModels[] products;
    }
```

Instead fields you can define properties.
and you method should look like:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/pag_seguro/transactions/credit_card")]
public string DoTransactionWithCreditCard(PayRequest request)
{
     // ...
     return "ok";
}
```